# Copy text from webview using a button script inside the loaded html file

Tags: javascript, android

So i have a working button on my html file that copies the text inside a span or div. but when i load inside my WebView. the button doesnt work anymore. any idea whats happening here? TIA

Comment: You need to post some code if you want a proper answer.

Is this really a Javascript question? Are you coding your app in React Native or similar? How are you sending the text from the button to the WebView?

Comment: sorry if i didnt posted the code and for the wrong tags. it turns out that the code is not working inside the emulator but works on my Phone. Thanks for the help anyways.